# Do I use AWK, SED or Grep from Bash to echo/print to specify variables from select fields from multiple lines of log file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, command-line-interface

I am trying to parse read only comm logs from a radio. Some entries are 2-3 lines others might be more than 8 lines. The good news is I can find unique static start and stop strings. The bad news is I have tried copying SED code from the nearest example I could find for the past 11 hours with zero success.

The log looks like this:

```
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:24.927 DMR Slot 2, received network voice header from KS3X to TG 91
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:25.402 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 6/20 char): 'KS3X D'
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:25.410 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Header
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:25.412 0000:  04 00 68 4B 53 33 58 20 44  *..hKS3XD*
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:26.111 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 13/20 char): 'KS3X DMR ID: '
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:26.120 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Block 1
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:26.121 0000:  05 00 4D 52 20 49 44 3A 20  *..MR ID: *
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:26.824 DMR Talker Alias (Data Format 1, Received 20/20 char): 'KS3X DMR ID: 1142129'
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:26.824 DMR Slot 2, Embedded Talker Alias Block 2
M: 2019-06-08 18:15:26.824 0000:  06 00 31 31 34 32 31 32 39  *..1142129*
M: 2019-06-08 18:16:15.921 DMR Slot 2, received network end of voice transmission, 51.2 seconds, 0% packet loss, BER: 0.0%
```

**The data variables I would want from that would be the following:**

1. The call sign between 'from' and 'to' on line 1.
2. The channel located between 'to' and the end of line 1.
3. The DMR ID at the end of line 8(1142129).
4. The duration of 51.2 seconds on line 11.
5. The percentage of packet loss on line 11.
6. The percentage of BER at the end of line 11.

All records, no matter their length of lines start with "received voice header from" and end with the "%" percent symbol. Additionally could anyone point me toward a low level overview of when to use SED, GREP or AWK, they all seem very similar to me? Just a link to a good tutorial would be great.

What I am trying to is run a bash script to monitor the log using the terminal using something like this:
tail -fn0 /var/log/pi-star/MMDVM-2019-06-08.log

But with only the 6 variables named above. Super grateful!!!

```
#!/bin/bash
ACCESS_TOKEN="o.WOgpVaaEBjoVLGKS3VzFnsO4xGClTRiF"
tail -fn0 /var/log/pi-star/MMDVM-2019-06-08.log | \

while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | gawk '
  match($0, /received.*voice header from ([[:alnum:]]+) to ([[:alnum:]]+ [0-9]+)/, a) {
    in_record = 1
    call_sign = a[1]
    channel = a[2]
  }
  in_record && match($0, /DMR ID: ([0-9]+)/, a) {
    dmr_id = a[1]
  }
  in_record && match($0, /([0-9.]+) seconds, ([0-9]+)% packet loss, BER: ([0-9.]+)%/, a) {
    in_record = 0
    print call_sign, channel, dmr_id, a[1], a[2], a[3]
  }
'
done
```

Comment: This would be a prefect log to analyze in Splunk. (free software for use up to 500MB log/day)

Comment: For overviews of those tools, click on the tags, then click the "Learn more..." links on the tag info pages.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it is too expensive for hobby use, too complex to setup an SSH connection to the host, too laggy to monitor and send pushbullet API alerts from after being slowed by another pipe in the middle and too heavy on my storage space at 867MB I appreciate your reply though.

Comment: @JaeNulton expensive not, since its free to use. But complex and some time consuming to learn, but result is amazing.

Comment: Of the suggested tools, Awk is by the the best for this.  While you could in theory use `sed`, it would be very cumbersome (at best) to do the job well.  Using grep would be fiddly, with a lot a lot of reassembly required by the calling script.  Awk was  designed for this sort of text transformation.

Comment: Use sed for `s/old/new` on individual strings. Use grep for `g/re/p` on individual strings. For anything else use awk for clarity, portability, efficiency, and easy of maintenance/enhancement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gawk '
  match($0, /received.*voice header from ([[:alnum:]]+) to ([[:alnum:]]+ [0-9]+)/, a) {
    in_record = 1
    call_sign = a[1]
    channel = a[2]
  }
  in_record && match($0, /DMR ID: ([0-9]+)/, a) {
    dmr_id = a[1]
  }
  in_record && match($0, /([0-9.]+) seconds, ([0-9]+)% packet loss, BER: ([0-9.]+)%/, a) {
    in_record = 0
    print call_sign, channel, dmr_id, a[1], a[2], a[3]
  }
' OFS=, radio.log
```

```
KS3X,TG 91,1142129,51.2,0,0.0
```

This is specific to GNU awk (for the 3-argument form of the match() function)

Comment: My previous command worked in a bash script, is there something that inherently would not allow GAWK to work within bash?

Comment: As far as bash is concerned, gawk is just like any other exrenal command that can be found in the $PATH.

Comment: Thank you for the help Glenn, I've got some learning to do. Thanks to the others who posted helpful suggestions as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` (standard Linux `gawk`) script doing the same trick. with less code and better capture patterns.

`script.awk`

```
/received network voice header from/,/#$/{
    if (match($0, "from ([^ ]+) to (.*$)", a)) {
        output[1] = a[1];
        output[2] = a[2];
    }
    if (match($0, "DMR ID: ([^']+)'", a)) {
        output[3] = a[1];
    }
    if (match($0, "voice transmission, ([^ ]+) seconds, ([^%]+)% packet loss, BER: ([^%]+)%", a)) {
        output[4] = a[1];
        output[5] = a[2];
        output[6] = a[3];

        outputStr =  output[1];
        for (i = 2; i <= 6; i++) outputStr = outputStr","output[i];
        print outputStr;
    }
}
```

run script

```
awk -f script.awk input.log
```

output:

```
KS3X,TG 91,1142129,51.2,0,0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='%\n' -v OFS=, '{print $12, $14" "$15, $112+0, $150, $152+0, $156}' file
KS3X,TG 91,1142129,51.2,0,0.0
```